# Is recombination suppressed in the males of all Drosophila species? Any other species?

Tags: recombination, drosophila

[Following up from this question,](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/7267/why-doesnt-recombination-occur-in-male-drosophila) I am wondering if the phenomenon of genome-wide suppressed male recombination is limited to *Drosophila melanogaster* or is common to all *Drosophila*? The answer to the aforementioned question hints that this may be the case but has no reference on that, and doesn't directly state it.

For an added bonus, is this recorded in any other species?