# Is complete linkage found in all four chromosomes or only Y-chromosome of Drosophila?

Tags: chromosome, drosophila, genetic-linkage

Male Drosophila shows complete linkage. Is it observed for all four chromosomes or only the Y chromosome?

Answer (score 4):

All chromosomes. There is no crossing over in males in Drosophila. Check out the related question [Why doesn't recombination occur in male Drosophila?](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/7267/why-doesnt-recombination-occur-in-male-drosophila) for sources and context.

Comment: Hi @Christiaan, could you clarify your comment? I thought the OP was asking if the complete linkage in male Drosophila was for all chromosomes or just the Y, to which the answer is "all".

Comment: I don't question the validity of the answer, but the norm at Bio is to elaborate on your answer. For example, where did you obtain your answer from (references, sources)? Why is it all the chromosomes and not one? How do you know? As of now, it's a one-liner and this is generally not suitable as an answer, but more as a comment.

Comment: +1. However, it makes me wonder if this question is a dupe from your linked post?

Comment: Probably? Not sure how these things work.